# Неудачная попытка выполнить команду -a fixpermissions

Tags: php, mysql, linux, vmware

Устанавливаю образ Kali Linux на EVE-NG. Скачал официальную сборку linux, разархивировал, далее необходимо воспользоваться командой

```
/opt/unetlab/wrappers/unl_wrapper -a fixpermissions
```

При первой попытке вылезла ошибка:

> PHP Warning: file_get_contents (/opt/unetlab/platform/): failed to
> open stream: No such file or directory in
> /opt/unetlab/html/includes/init.php on line 71

После удаления "platform" из 71 строчки в файле, произошла еще одна ошибка связанная с БД, как мне кажется (уже не помню точно). Далее попытался обновить пакеты и включил команды

```
sudo apt update     
sudo apt upgrade
```

После перезагрузки начала появляться следующая ошибка

> sudo: /opt/unetlab/wrappers/unl_wrapper: command not found

Без *sudo*:

> -bash: /opt/unetlab/wrappers/unl_wrapper: Permission denied

Уже все возможное перетыкал и все излазил, но так и ничего пока не получается.

Также есть проблема с дисковым пространством и работой MySQL. Диск заполнен на 89% без чего либо работающего на ВМ, от этого не работает как минимум вход в веб-интерфейс в EVE в браузере. Где то видел "помощников", которые советовали добавить в ВМ еще один диск, чтобы прибавить памяти, однако на ВМ и так выделено 300 GB, и на 250GB там работать нечему.

На официальном сайте указана длинная команда по решению этой проблемы, но я так полагаю основная команда эта:

```
unl_wrapper -a restoredb
```

Так же заканчивается последними ошибками.

Comment: https://github.com/dainok/unetlab/blob/master/wrappers/unl_wrapper.php - ссылка на исполняемый файл.

Answer (score 0):

Если после запуска `fixpermissions` в консоле `EVE-NG` вы получили ошибку:

> PHP Warning: file_get_contents (/opt/unetlab/platform/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/unetlab/html/includes/init.php on line 71

, то не надо удалять "`platform`" из 71 строчки файла `/opt/unetlab/html/includes/init.php` . Это вредный совет, который вы можете встретить в сети Интернет.

Вместо этого, для устранения ошибки следует выполнить следующий набор команд на сервере `EVE-NG`:

(*все команды должны выполняться от пользователя root*)

Запустите в терминале команду:

```
dmesg | grep -i cpu | grep -i -e intel -e amd
```

если в выводе будет содержаться слово "`Intel`"

тогда выполните команду:

```
echo "intel" > /opt/unetlab/platform
```

если в выводе будет содержаться слово "`amd`", тогда выполните:

```
echo "amd" > /opt/unetlab/platform
```

После этого можно снова запустить команду:

```
/opt/unetlab/wrappers/unl_wrapper -a fixpermissions
```

Надеюсь, это поможет решить проблему с запуском `unl_wrapper -a fixpermissions`